# Installing the hive with mysql

Tags: mysql, hive, configuration, connection

I am able to install the Hive and MySQL in centos env, by following these steps:

- Install MySQL
- Copy mysql-connector-java.jar into $HIVE_HOME/lib
- Configure the hive-site.xml (reference : [link](https://data-flair.training/blogs/configure-hive-metastore-to-mysql/))
- init DB type MySQL and start hive metastore

The metastore_db is created in mysql once I run the command `schematool -initschema -dbtype mysql` .

However, once I checked the database in Hive, it only showed the database default, instead of showing all the databases created in MySQL.

I've double-confirmed that all the configurations in hive-site.xml are correct. What could be wrong with my step? Did I miss any of the important configs to install hive with MySQL as its database?

DB in MySQL:
[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRsEK.png)

DB in Hive:
[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZiFt.png)